# how can i make a list of dictionary from the dictionary where values are a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

i have a dictionary with three key-value pairs and in which the values are a list. I want to create a list of the dictionary where the keys are string and values of that dictionary should be the value of list from each dictionary values,

I thought of iterating over that dictionary and do list comprehension where each element is a dictionary but I can't get the value for that key.

```
cars = {
        'cars' : ['audi', 'bmw', 'xyz'],
        'model' : ['abc', 'qwer', 'rty']
    }

car_list = [{'car': value_audi, 'car-model': value_abc} for car in cars]

how can I get this value_audi and value_abc for each list item?
```

the result should be like this

```
car_list = [{'cars': audi, 'car_model': abc}, {'cars': bmw, 'car_model': qwer}, {'cars': xyz, 'car_model': rty}]
```

Comment: `cars['cars'][i]` always corresponds to `cars['model'][i]`…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip(*)`:

```
car_list = [{'car': x, 'car_model': y} for x, y in zip(*cars.values())]
```

**Example**:

```
cars = {
        'cars' : ['audi', 'bmw', 'xyz'],
        'model' : ['abc', 'qwer', 'rty']
    }

car_list = [{'car': x, 'car_model': y} for x, y in zip(*cars.values())]

# [{'car': 'audi', 'car_model': 'abc'}, {'car': 'bmw', 'car_model': 'qwer'}, {'car': 'xyz', 'car_model': 'rty'}]
```

Comment: The order of values in the dict may not be so reliable, depending on your Python version and/or on where the input is coming from.

Comment: It works! but can u explain me the zip(*cars.values())? i have used zip before but never this way...@Austin

Comment: `cars.values()` returns a `dict_values` which here is a list of lists (list holding each of the list values). `zip(*)` will iterate parallel through each list in this list of lists.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

**Ex.**

```
cars = {
        'cars' : ['audi', 'bmw', 'xyz'],
        'model' : ['abc', 'qwer', 'rty']
    }

result = [{'cars':c,'car_model':m} for c,m in zip(cars['cars'],cars['model']) ]
print(result)
```

**O/P:**

```
[{'cars': 'audi', 'car_model': 'abc'}, {'cars': 'bmw', 'car_model': 'qwer'}, {'cars': 'xyz', 'car_model': 'rty'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to "hardcode" the keys of your new dicts you can use:

```
from itertools import cycle

cars = {
        'cars' : ['audi', 'bmw', 'xyz'],
        'model' : ['abc', 'qwer', 'rty']
    }

[dict(e) for e in zip(*[zip(cycle([k]), v) for k, v in cars.items()])]
```

output:

```
[{'cars': 'audi', 'model': 'abc'},
 {'cars': 'bmw', 'model': 'qwer'},
 {'cars': 'xyz', 'model': 'rty'}]
```

Comment: @PrithviSingh is fine with "model" key, or you want "cras_model"  key?

Answer (score 0):

Zip() can help you here.

The purpose of zip() is to map the similar index of multiple containers so that they can be used just using as single entity.

```
cars = {
    'cars' : ['audi', 'bmw', 'xyz'],
    'model' : ['abc', 'qwer', 'rty']
}

result = [{'cars':x,'car_model':y} for x,y in zip(cars['cars'],cars['model']) ]
print(result)
```

Expected output will be :

```
[{'cars': 'audi', 'car_model': 'abc'}, {'cars': 'bmw', 'car_model': 'qwer'}, {'cars': 'xyz', 'car_model': 'rty'}]
```

follow this link for further clarification [zip()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/)